# How do I authorise my YouTube API key to access my Youtube channel?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm querying the Youtube Data API (v3) to access my Youtube channel and retrive its subscriptions, but I'm continually hitting a "403 The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions."

I've tried:

`GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId=[channelID]&key=[key]` and

`GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId=[channelID]&forUsername=[username]&key=[key]`

I've checked my API key set-up and You Tube is definitely enabled on that key.

So how do I convince the API that that's my channel? It's a Brand Channel, but has the same primary email address as the one associated with the API key?

Do I have to do a 0Auth, or is there some other method?

Answer (score 0):

As per the official specification of the [`Subscriptions.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) API endpoint, if you want to get your own subscriptions, then invoke the endpoint with the request parameter `mine` set to `true`:

> [**`mine`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#mine) boolean
> This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Set this parameter's value to `true` to retrieve a feed of the authenticated user's subscriptions.

Do note that for this to work, you'll have to invoke the endpoint upon completing successfully an OAuth 2 authentication and authorization flow.

The OAuth2 flow is a requirement that cannot be avoided and it cannot be substituted with anything else.

As a result of the OAuth flow, you'll obtain an access token that you'll have to pass on to the endpoint either as the request parameter `access_token` or as an HTTP header of form:

`Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN`.

In any case, the request parameter `key` becomes superfluous, and can safely be left out from the API invoking URL.

Comment: Yes, it is explained; assuming your app is of *desktop* kind: [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps).

Comment: yes apologies. I deleted my earlier comment after I saw that.